Kronecker product arising from a coproduct
I'm reading a paper that involves some background on linear algebra, and I came across a sentence that I'm trying to make sense of:
"The tensor/Kronecker product $\otimes$ of representations corresponds to the symmetric monoidal product on the category of $k[x]$-modules arising from the coproduct $k[x]\rightarrow k[x]\otimes_k k[x]$ sending $x$ to $x\otimes x$."
Can anyone shed some light on this story? How does one go from the coproduct mentioned, to a symmetric monoidal product on $k[x]$-modules, and finally, associate this with the Kronecker product of representations?
Thank you!

I will assume that $k$ is a field. A $k[x]$-module consists of a $k$-vector space $V$ together with a $k$-algebra map $\varphi_V\colon k[x]\to\mathrm{End}_k(V)$. As such, given two $k[x]$-modules $V$ and $W$, we can consider the $k$-vector space $V\otimes_k W$, and this gives us a $k$-algebra homomorphism $$k[x]\otimes_k k[x]\xrightarrow{\varphi_V\otimes_k\varphi_W}\mathrm{End}_k(V)\otimes_k\mathrm{End}_k(W)\to\mathrm{End}_k(V\otimes_k W),$$ where the last map is given by $(f\colon V\to V,g\colon W\to W)\mapsto (f\otimes_k g\colon V\otimes_k W\to V\otimes_k W)$. Now, we have a $k$-algebra morphism $k[x]\to k[x]\otimes_k k[x]$ induced by $x\mapsto x\otimes x$, which is called a coproduct by the author. Note that this has nothing to do with a categorical coproduct, but is just called so because it is dual to the product operation $k[x]\otimes_k k[x]\to k[x]$ encoding the multiplication in the $k$-algebra $k[x]$. The composite
$$
k[x]\xrightarrow{x\mapsto x\otimes x}k[x]\otimes_k k[x]\xrightarrow{\varphi_V\otimes_k\varphi_W}\mathrm{End}_k(V)\otimes_k\mathrm{End}_k(W)\to\mathrm{End}_k(V\otimes_k W)
$$
is a $k$-algebra homomorphism, and hence gives $V\otimes_k W$ the structure of a $k[x]$-module. In this way, the symmetric monoidal structure on $k$-vector spaces given by the tensor product lifts to a symmetric monoidal structure on $k[x]$-modules.
You probably know how representations are linked to $k[x]$-modules. If you figure out what the representation corresponding to the $k[x]$-module $V\otimes_k W$ is, you will see that it is the one obtained by a Kronecker product of the representations corresponding to the $k[x]$-modules $V$ and $W$.
